# Get Metadata for a track in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I'm working on  Xcode-Swift-Spotify project, The only thing that I want is to get info about the song which is currently playing,info I mean name, album and so on, I've tried in so many different ways but I can't get it. Please help me. There is an example below

```
func audioStreaming(audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didStartPlayingTrack trackUri: NSURL!)
{

    SPTTrack.trackWithURI(self.player?.currentTrackURI, session: spotifyAuthenticator.session) { (error:NSError!, track:AnyObject!) -> Void in

        print(track.name)

    }}
```

I forgot to say, I'm working with the Spotify SDK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I show you my example

```
 var avpItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: megaURL)
            var commonMetaData = avpItem.asset.commonMetadata as! [AVMetadataItem]
            for item in commonMetaData {
                if item.commonKey == "title" {
                    songTitle = item.stringValue
                }
                if item.commonKey == "artist" {
                    songArtist = item.stringValue
                }
                if item.commonKey == "album" {
                    songAlbum = item.stringValue
                }
                if item.commonKey == "artwork" {
                    songArtworkData = item.dataValue
                }
```

Metadata's keywords

```
let AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyCreator: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeySubject: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyDescription: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyPublisher: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyContributor: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyCreationDate: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyLastModifiedDate: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyType: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyFormat: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyIdentifier: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeySource: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyLanguage: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyRelation: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyLocation: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyCopyrights: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyAlbumName: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyAuthor: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyArtist: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyMake: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeyModel: String
let AVMetadataCommonKeySoftware: String
```